# How to get only the date part?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I'm trying to get only the date part in the file name. For eg:

```
abc-xyz20140417.tar
abc-20120420.tar
abc-efghi19800815.tar
```

Output needed:

```
20140417
20120420
19800815
```

Comment: `grep -oP '\d{8}' filename`

Answer (score 0):

If the number characters in the filenames are only the date which is required for you, then here is an example:

```
root@localhost:~[0]$ ls -1 abc-*
abc-20120420.tar
abc-efghi19800815.tar
abc-xyz20140417.tar
root@localhost:~[0]$ ls -1 abc-*  | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
20120420
19800815
20140417
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date is always the last 8 characters before ".tar", this will work with any sed on any OS:

```
$ sed 's/.*\(........\).tar$/\1/' file
20140417
20120420
19800815
```